# charting trendlines together

Tags: excel, charts, static

I need to display this kind of data in one chart:

[image: data.png]

Which means:

Function A: Y= X + 10 ;

Function B: Y= X * 2 ;

but what I got from excel is:

[image: chart.png]

Actually what I want is (sorry for the drawing):

[image: chart2.png]

---

My real data is like:

[image: data.png]

If I format it like this:

[image: data.png]

I can still not get the correct charts.

Comment: On chart selection make sure you don't click cumulative line graph (i.e values stacked on top of each other), which will prevent your lines from starting at the same point (10,20)

Answer (score 4):

***Updated to account for change of question***

Your data structure is wrong to achieve this in Excel, see for example:
[image]

On the left you want your x axis values, don't put a header in this column otherwise it will plotted on your graph as a series (extra line).

You can fill in gaps in your data with `#N/A` and excel will ignore these points, joining the line to the next available point.

Comment: Thansk for the answer, but I still have a small problem drawing my data, I described below the original question.

Comment: @PingjiangLi Out of interest I've come back to this question and found a solution to your extended problem.